# The site does not accept drag-and-dropped comment

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface, usability

In a comment, I have dragged-and-dropped some text.

Now the comment text area has my comment, and I want to post it. So I click on *Add Comment*.

But this does not work.

The site keeps telling me to enter at least 15 characters. Although I have entered way more than 15 chars.

It would be nice to correct this bug. Thank you.

I have Firefox 26.

Comment: Works in Chrome. In Firefox you have to click into the comment box afterwards to cause an update.

Comment: Firefox 16 on my linux box works, firefox 21 on my mac works and firefox 28 on my windows box works.

Comment: @MaQleod - Probably you are not doing exactly the same steps.

Comment: @MaQleod - In Firefox 26 on Win 7, I reproduce the bug.

Comment: FireFox 28 also works fine for me... I wonder if it's a fault with that version (or prior to 28) or something else local to you only?

Comment: @Dave — On Firefox 28 on my Mac, I reproduce the bug. In Safari Mac too, albeit with a slightly different behaviour.